# C++ Polymorphic Static Changeable Child Function Pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, function-pointers, static-polymorphism

I have a class A that is a child of class B, I need all children of class B to have a function pointer to a function for handling the class that is changeable by an external function in a different file after the classes have been compiled.  All instances of class A should point to one function, and all instances of B should point to a function, but A and B should be able to point to different functions.  How can I do this? I have tried a static function pointer and a private static function pointer but neither have worked.

```
class B{
    public:
    static void (* func)();
}
class A : public B{

}
class C : public B{

}
void funcA(){
    cout<<"A"<<endl;
}
void funcB(){
    cout<<"B"<<endl;
}
void funcC(){
    cout<<"C"<<endl;
}
void main(){
    B b=B();
    B b2=B();
    B a=A();
    B a2=A();
    B c=C();
    B c2=C();
    b.func=funcB;
    a.func=funcA;
    c.func=funcC;
    a.func();
    b.func();
    c.func();
    a2.func();
    b2.func();
    c2.func();
}
```

My desired output is

```
B
A
C
B
A
C
```

Comment: If I create a `B` object, and pass it to a function that takes an `A&` reference, and that function uses the pointer from that object reference, should it see the pointer associated with `A` objects or the pointer associated with `B` objects?

Comment: I dont think you would be able to pass B to func(A&) as A is the child, but if you could I would want the pointer for B

Comment: Whoops, yes, I had those backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all instances of a derived class to share the same function-pointer you need to put one function-pointer in each class.

It's not clear from your question if you want polymorphic behaviour from the classes, but I assumed so in this answer. If you combine virtual functions and a static function pointer you can get the behavior your looking for.

```
#include <iostream>

using fptr = void (*)();

class B {
    public:
    virtual void func() {
        bfunc();
    }
    static fptr bfunc;
};
fptr B::bfunc;

class A : public B{
    public:
    void func() override {
        afunc();
    }
    static fptr afunc;
};
fptr A::afunc;

class C : public B{
    public:
    void func() override {
        cfunc();
    }
    static fptr cfunc;
};
fptr C::cfunc;

void funcA(){
    std::cout<<"A"<<std::endl;
}
void funcB(){
    std::cout<<"B"<<std::endl;
}
void funcC(){
    std::cout<<"C"<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    B b=B();
    B b2=B();
    A a=A();
    A a2=A();
    C c=C();
    C c2=C();
    B::bfunc=funcB;
    A::afunc=funcA;
    C::cfunc=funcC;
    a.func();
    b.func();
    c.func();
    a2.func();
    b2.func();
    c2.func();

    B* c3 = new C;
    c3->func();
    delete c3;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to do it without having a uniquely named funnction pointer?

Comment: @JesseMcDonald Yes, the function pointer in A, B and C can all have the same name.

Comment: ok, I found out what my problem was when I tired that... I messed up the polymorphic part so it looked like it was not working....